# DataGridView loop selected cells C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I've got a function that quickly applies values to a range of selected cells

It works well, unless the column has been clicked by the user (sorted) then it appears to try assigning the value to the same row multiple times.

Can anyone help?

```
private static void QuickFill()
        {
            String inputVal = InputBox.Show("", "Assign value to all selected cells");
            if (inputVal is null) return;
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in DGV.SelectedCells)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (cell.ReadOnly == false)
                    {

                        if (inputVal == "")
                        {
                            cell.Value = DBNull.Value;
                        }
                        else if (cell.GetType().Name == "DataGridViewComboBoxCell")
                        {
                            string cmbString = "";
                            DataGridViewComboBoxCell cmbCell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)cell;
                            foreach (var itm in cmbCell.Items)
                            {
                                if (itm.GetType() == typeof(DataRowView))
                                {
                                    DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)itm;
                                    cmbString = drv.Row.ItemArray[0].ToString();
                                }
                                if (itm.GetType() == typeof(string))
                                {
                                    cmbString = itm.ToString();
                                }
                                if (cmbString.ToLower()==inputVal.ToLower())
                                {
                                    cell.Value = cmbString;
                                }
                            }
                            
                        } 
                        else
                        {
                            cell.Value = inputVal;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    //ignore
                    continue;
                }
            }
            DGV.Focus();
        }
```

I've tried manually setting the sorting and then assigning the value.

I've also tried putting the value in the cell tag, then looping and assigning the tag (from a while until no tags are found) and I pretty much get the same happening